# How can i correct linting python import when use zc.buildout in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint, buildout

I created a python django project use `zc.buildout` but in vscode pylint cannot recognize the imports in eggs.

The error:

> [pylint] E0401:Unable to import 'django.test'

Comment: Can Pylint recognize the imports outside of VS Code?

Comment: It's because when using `zc.buildout`, it will create a `./bin/python` script as an interpreter of the project and adds `./eggs` modules to python path. But if I set `./bin/python` of the vscode interpreter, then pylint won't work. I don't know how to config vscode...

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable with a `.env` file and that will be used when running Pylint.